# How to solve an "Error found when retrieving conflicts." error in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-9.3, versioning

I uncovered this error when testing ArcMap 10 SP2 for a customer:
[image]

This occurs when the conflict is detected--ArcMap is attempting to show the conflicts window but fails.

I get this error on all workstations at the customer's location (all Windows XP).  But I don't get the error on my systems (I've tried XP and Windows 7).

I've tried various oracle/sql server combinations and I still receive the error on the customer's workstation.

It appears to be a compatibility issue and I have an open Esri incident which hasn't yielded any results, so I thought I'd tap the gis.se.

Has anyone experienced this error with this set(or similar set) of conditions?

*Update From Comments:*
I initially got this in an Oracle10/9.3.1 sde database, but also replicated the error with a sqlexpress/arcsde 10.  I only have this issue with the customer's ArcGIS Desktop workstations and each experience the same issue.

**Data from crash:**

```
00:04:14.578: First chance exception 0xC0000005 (Access Violation) occurred in "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\VERSIONUI.DLL" at address 0x39458983.
00:04:14.578: LoadLibraryW("DbgHelp.dll") called from "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\AFCORE.DLL" at address 0x00714A04.
00:04:14.594: Loaded "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\DBGHELP.DLL" at address 0x0B770000.  Successfully hooked module.
00:04:14.594: DllMain(0x0B770000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\DBGHELP.DLL" called.
00:04:14.594: DllMain(0x0B770000, DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, 0x00000000) in "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\DBGHELP.DLL" returned 1 (0x1).
00:04:14.594: LoadLibraryW("DbgHelp.dll") returned 0x0B770000.
00:04:14.610: GetProcAddress(0x0B770000 [c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\DBGHELP.DLL], "MiniDumpWriteDump") called from "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\AFCORE.DLL" at address 0x00714A14 and returned 0x0B7CD4F0.
00:04:14.610: Second chance exception 0xC0000005 (Access Violation) occurred in "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\VERSIONUI.DLL" at address 0x39458983.
00:04:14.657: Exited "c:\program files\arcgis\desktop10.0\bin\ARCMAP.EXE" (process 0xC0C) with code -1073741819 (0xC0000005).
```

**New Information (8/4)**

- Client is getting this in ArcGIS 9.3.1 as well--they so seldom get
  conflicts that this hasn't been an issue until now.
- I'm nearly certain that this issue is caused by some other software that was pushed out to these machines.  *We're still troubleshooting and I'll update this question with an answer once I know more.*

Comment: Do you have any idea what kind of conflict has occurred? Are you replicating the exact same type of conflict on your systems?

Comment: Yes. In the ArcGIS 10 environment we are intentionally creating both shape and attribute conflicts and doing reconciles by object and by attribute which are usual tests we do.

Comment: Do either shape or attribute conflicts cause the above error, or just one of them? I remember having an incident where a particular type of shape conflict was causing this crash for us, but I do not remember exactly what the nature of the conflict was. (And, I think it might have only been on a machine that had FME/Interoperability extension installed on it, which I know has been the source of some object loading bugs in the past.)

Comment: both types cause the crash.  I'll also point out that I have the exact same ArcGIS 10 config (and installed from the same media) on non-imaged/non-managed machines and those do not have this issue (I connected to the same database and used the same conflicted version).

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a ArcSDE version change from the service pack.

ArcSDE 10 Service Pack 2
http://resources.arcgis.com/content/patches-and-service-packs?fa=viewPatch&PID=66&MetaID=1748

Which Database are you using?

If Oracle this has been addressed:

**NIM058199** - If sde.version_user_ddl.edit_version('t1',1) call errors out due to lock conflict, it will issue a commit which can affect other pending transactions.

Comment: I initially got this in an Oracle10/9.3.1 sde database, but also replicated the error with a sqlexpress/arcsde 10.  I only have this issue with the customer's ArcGIS Desktop workstations and each experience the same issue.